# Trouble with logfile output - difference between string and c_str - C++

Tags: c++, string, logging

I am trying to finalize my logging class. I have written it from scratch and do not wish to use an alternative library of any kind. My problem lies within the fact that my logger has trouble outputting `std::string`s and only works when I denote it with the `string.c_str()` function.

Here is my logfile output function:

```
void Log::writeSuccess(char * text,...)
{
    // Grab the variables and insert them
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, text);
    char buff[BUFFER_SIZE];
    vsnprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), text, ap);

    // Output to the log
    logfile << "<-!-> " << buff << endl;
}
```

Here is a sample call to my log class object (ignore the uselessness of the call):

```
string test("This is a test string!");
errorLog.writeSuccess("Output: %s", test);
```

I end up with random characters and garbled output.

However, when I append the string, `test` with `.c_str()`, it outputs the text correctly.

The whole reason I am trying to avoid cstrings is because I understand they are not cross platform and am developing my client to support all the major operating systems.

To summarize:

1. What is wrong with my log output function? Do you see any way it could be improved?
2. Should I generally avoid c_strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting random garble when passing an `std::string` to `vsnprintf` because the format specifier `"%s"` is that of a C-string - a `char*`.

`std::string` is **not** of type `char*`, but `std::string.c_str()` **is** of type `char*`. `vsnprintf` will basically read `char`s pointed to by the address that *it presumes is that of a start of a C-string*, up until the NUL character `'\0'`.

An `std::string` pushed onto the stack and passed as an argument to `vsnprintf` is not a pointer to a `char`, however `vsnprintf` will just treat these bytes as an address and start reading `char`s/bytes from this address, causing undefined behaviour.

The `printf` family of functions are not typesafe, since they rely on a format string and variable argument list, which is why your code will compile but you'll get unexpected results.

Bottom line is the `printf` family of functions expect a `char*` when you use the format specifier `"%s"`.

I also think you're confusing C style strings (`char[]`) with the Microsoft-specific [`CString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174288.aspx) class. C style strings won't cause you problems on different platforms at all; the literal `"This is a test string!"` is a C style string (`const char[]`).

Answer (score 1):

When calling function with variable parameters you must use simple types. For `string` you must use `c_str()`. There's no workaround. MFC's `CString` is designed so that you can get away with using it directly, but that was Microsoft's decision, and part of their design.

EDIT: As I said when calling function with variable parameters you **must** use string::c_str(). However, instead of C-like functions with variable parameters you can use something like [`boost::format()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) and it's parameter feeding operator %. This also gives you more control over ordering of parameters, which is very handy for [i18n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I18n).

Comment: Are you saying that I have to give up on the ability to have this cross platform or just the way I wrote my logfile is incompatible with a string without the Cstring. Do you have any suggestions for rewriting my logfile output? How do other logging classes get away with outputting strings?

Comment: You don't have to give up anything. Just write `errorLog.writeSuccess("Output: %s", test.c_str());` instead, as it is explained by numerous C++ tutorials, which you hopefully have read and understood.

Comment: @hiobs This answer did not initially explain that there is indeed a difference between C and C style strings. Can't fault the asker for now knowing.

Comment: @SatchmoBrown Gotcha. No offense intended.